# custom snippet extender Ultisnips

Tags: vimrc, gvim, plugin-ultisnips

Suppose I have a snippet:

```
snippet prg 
    !This is file : `!v expand('%:t:r')`
    ! Author= `!v expand($USER)`
    ! Started at: `date +%d.%m.%y`
    ! Last Modified : Sun 16 Jun 2019 12:30:58 IST
    !
    Program  ${1:<++`!v expand('%:t:r')`}
    Implicit None
    ${2}
    End Program  ${1/([^\n$]+).*/$1/}
endsnippet
...
```

and in vimrc, i have: `let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<c-a>"`

which is working fine.

Now, besides this, I am trying to have a keymap, like say, `"prg` in `insertmode`, which will expand this snippet for me. eg:

`inoremap "prg :some_magic_(expand_snippet_prg)`

any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use remap to trigger expansion**

```
imap "prg prg<c-a>
```

or

```
exe printf('imap "prg prg%s',  g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger)
```

But not this:

```
imap <expr> "prg 'prg' . g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger
```

`g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger` is a variable, `map` won't figure out special key code of it's value for you.

**Manual expansion**

```
inoremap "prg prg<c-r>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<cr>
```

You can't use `<expr>` here, as `<expr>` can't change buffer text.

You dont need to call `expand` on `enviroment variable`, `$USER` is enough.